# Merging multiple identical access database

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have started working on an existing frontend MS Access application built with VBA. It is linked to a backend Access database. So basically there are two Access databases - one frontend and one backend.

Because of the nature of the work involving vehicles, each user has their own copy of identical database with their individual data stored in backend. Constant Access to one backend db via internet is not really possible as the users are able to connect to internet (network) once a day only. Right now we just copy each backend database via ftp and store it as usr_backenddb_date.accdb

Backend databases contain around 16 tables with most of them containing an autonumber field as a primary key. Further tables are connected with each other referencing the primary key as a foreign key. I would ideally like to create a function in vba that lets me select the database and merge all the data from that database to an identical central database. For the initial part, I am thinking of doing something like this [How to merge two identical database data to one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042007/how-to-merge-two-identical-database-data-to-one) with possibly trying to cascade the change in autonumber field so the references remain intact.

I wanted to know if this approach is doable or if anyone has any other ideas and suggestion that I can look into.

Comment: Certainly doable, just takes lots of code. I have built 2 projects that required periodic merging of 'remote user' files to central db. One used autonumber PK and one did not. The autonumber version was definitely trickier. For the autonumber version I had no control over the db structure, the files were provided by a contractor. For the other db, I designed and made decision not to use any autonumber PK in order to simplify import.